# Wanted to check pointwise limit of $(1+\sin(x/n))^n \:\forall x \in \mathbb{R} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

So I thought that the point wise limit would just be:

$$f (x) = \begin{cases} 
1 &\mbox{if } x=0 \\ 
0 & \mbox{if } x<0\\
\infty & \mbox{if } x>0
 \end{cases}  $$

If this is wrong could I have some hints please

Comment: Take the logarithm and use Taylor approximations (for $n$ large enough, depending on $\lvert x\rvert$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(1+\sin (\frac  x n))^{n}=(1+\frac x n +o(\frac 1 {n^{2}}))^{n} \to e^{x}$.

Comment: thanks, what does the O denote here

Comment: @DylanDijk $c_n=o(\frac 1 {n^{2}})$ means $n^{2}c_n \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for $x>0$, an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $n$ we obtain $${x\over n+\epsilon}\le \sin{x\over n}\le {x\over n}$$Hence 
$$\left(1+{x\over n+\epsilon}\right)^n\le \left(1+\sin{x\over n}\right)^n\le \left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n$$and we can write 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+{x\over n+\epsilon}\right)^n\le \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\sin{x\over n}\right)^n\le \lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+{x\over n}\right)^n$$The rightmost and leftmost $\lim$s are equal to $e^x$ and so must be the middle $\lim$. Same argument can be applied for $x\le 0$ to complete the proof.